# Rest service and web service in the same Spring Boot application

Tags: java, web-services, rest, spring-boot

Is it possible to have both Soap Web Service and and Rest service in the same Spring Boot application? I created class for handling WS request annotated with `@Endpoint` annotation and controller for REST service annotated with `@RestController` annotation.

When I run application with both of them requests for REST service are being handled by WS service which complains about SOAP envelope. When I run the same application only with REST controller everything works fine. So is it possible to configure somehow Spring Boot application to have both WS and REST service coexist?

Comment: Ok, I solved issue. It is possible to have them cooexisting. I changed url mapping for webservice from "/*" to "/ws".

Comment: just curious, what is the use case?

Comment: You can definitely, you can use multimodule maven project , 1 for SOAP based processing another for REST Based

Answer (score 0):

Possible, just use different URIs in mappings.
But I've put REST and WS mappings to different classes, just to be more convenient.